# SQL Server trigger how to do it?

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers, scripting

I need to create a trigger with this instruction:

Insertion trigger on table `FiestasProgramadas`, if I have a `distrito` with already a `fiesta_programada` for that month I need to display "There is already a fiesta"

Thanks for your help

Comment: A trigger isn't a good choice for *displaying* anything - it works silently in the background ...

Comment: If we do your homework for you, how would you learn? google "sql server instead of insert trigger".

Answer (score 2):

You don't need a trigger for this.  A unique constraint will do:

```
alter table FiestasProgramadas
    add constraint unq_FiestasProgramadas_distrito_mes on (distrito, mes);
```

I'm not sure what the column names are in your table, but this is the right idea.  If you have a date instead of a month, then you would need to add a computed column.

Comment: I need a trigger thats the question, I dont know how to do that on a trigger

Comment: A trigger is not the best way to approach this problem.

Comment: I know but I really need a trigger

Answer (score 0):

Although I agree with @Gordon Linoff, still here is insert trigger example for your reference.

http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/41414/sql-server-coding-the-after-insert-trigger-in-sql-server/